# Disable NERDTree window when opening file in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

Is there a way of disabling NERDTree when opening a file? When I open a file in mvim (using `--remote-silent`) and a NERDtree window is currently active, the file will open in that (narrow) window. How can I configure Vim to select another window if available and to open one if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to intercept the `--remote-silent`; you have to send explict commands to open the file with `--remote-send` instead. There, you can encode logic to deal with the NERDTree window, e.g. to move to the previous one if it is active:

```
$ gvim --remote-send "<C-\><C-n>:if &ft == 'nerdtree'|wincmd p|endif|edit filename<CR>"
```

Comment: Is there no way of configuring vim itself (i.e. put this logic in an 'on open' callback)?

Comment: I don't think there's a proper event, or you aren't allowed to switch windows in there, so that would only leave you to retroactively restore / shuffle the windows around.

Comment: Hm I see. Out of interest - how come --remote-silent doesn't take commands? The help said it did, but I tried it out and it seems like you're right.

Comment: The command(s) you can pass with --remote-silent are applied _after_ the file has been opened (e.g. to change an option); that doesn't help here.

Comment: On Windows, if gvim is not running, I get the "no server found message". Any way to avoid this?